# Get innerHTML value - only plain text

Tags: javascript, html, text

This is what i'm gonna do...

```js
alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  hi..my name is <div>Soul</div> and I am <strong>23 years old</strong>
  Thank you.
</div>
```

The alert box will show this:

```
hi..my name is <div>Soul</div> and I am <strong>23 years old</strong>Thank you.
```

But what I want inside the ALERT BOX is:

```
hi..my name is Soul and I am 23 years old Thank you.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** instead of **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** for getting text content instead of markup

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test').textContent);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  hi..my name is <div>Soul</div> and I am <strong>23 years old</strong>
  Thank you.
</div>
```

Comment: it works ...but i have a problem here... when there's an image inside the #test div, there will be a few newlines inside the alertbox. How to get rid all the newlines?

Comment: nevermind i just got the answer.... i use replace(/\n/g," "); by the way, thanksss!! problem solved!